# GNUPLOT: Plotting on the surface of a sphere

Tags: plot, geometry, gnuplot

I have a function dependent on phi and theta, which I want to plot on the surface of a sphere.
The date is stored in a .txt file with the columns:

```
1: x = R*sin(theta)*cos(phi)
2: y = R*sin(theta)*sin(phi)
3: z = R*cos(theta)
4: density
```

I use the following gnuplot code to plot:

```
set terminal wxt size 800,800
set mapping cartesian
set view equal xyz
set xlabel 'x'
set ylabel 'y'
set zlabel 'z'
splot "densityprofile_100.000.txt" u 1:2:3:4 with pm3d
pause -1
```

Unfortunately Gnuplot doesn't seem to be able to properly represent the colours on the sphere. There seems to be some shadow, which I can not get rid off; see the picture here:

[image]

When I turn the sphere with my mouse, the shadow gets smaller and bigger, but there is no position in which it fully disappears.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Please upload the image somehere and post the link. Then someone with higher reputation can include it for you. Also, please provide the data file, which allows to reproduce/test/fix your problem.

Comment: A guess: try using `set autoscale cbfix`, so that color range spans only exactly the values which you have in your data file.

Comment: Ok, I added the image inline. Could you also upload your data file somewhere? Without having it I cannot check what's wrong.

Comment: found the solution. if the datafile is still needed anyways for user users, let me know and i'll tryu to upload it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found the solution to my problem by adding the following line:

```
set pm3d depthorder
```

Answer (score 1):

At a guess, maybe the depth ordering is causing some trouble. Have you tried the pm3d "hidden3d" option?

from the gnuplot help on pm3d:

> The option hidden3d takes as the argument a linestyle which must be
>   created by set style line .... (The style need not to be present when
>   setting pm3d, but it must be present when plotting). If set, lines are
>   drawn using the specified line style, taking into account hidden line
>   removal. This is by far more efficient than using the command set
>   hidden3d as it doesn't really calculate hidden line removal, but just
>   draws the filled polygons in the correct order. So the recommended
>   choice when using pm3d is
>
> ```
>  set pm3d at s hidden3d 100
>  set style line 100 lt 5 lw 0.5
>  unset hidden3d
>  unset surf
>  splot x*x+y*y
> ```