# Gnuplot: contour surface plot with heatmap from isoline data

Tags: plot, gnuplot, heatmap, contour

I am trying to create a **heat map on a sphere, but with contour lines**.

### The Problem

If I understand correctly, it should work if I have a data file where each block contains one isoline of the heatmap on the surface, i.e. (x,y,z,iso_value). So far, I can only get the following result (due to size of data here for the first 3 blocks, i.e. 3 isolines):
[image: contour surface]
Obviously, **the contour is folded strangely**.

***The question is***: why does this happen and how can I fix it?

#### The script

```
set key at screen 1, 0.9, 0 right top vertical Right noreverse enhanced autotitle nobox
set style textbox opaque margins  0.5,  0.5 noborder

set title "contour on surface" 

set xlabel "X axis" 
set ylabel "Y axis" 
set zlabel "Z " 
set zlabel  offset character 1, 0, 0 font "" textcolor lt -1 norotate

set view 60, 30, 1, 1.1

##### Surface with Isolines
set hidden3d front
set pm3d depthorder

set mapping cartesian
splot 'cart_ed.txt' every :::0::2 using 1:2:3:4 with pm3d # plot surface
#splot 'cart_ed.txt' every :::0::2 using 1:2:3:4 w l # plot isolines
#############################
```

#### The data

This is the data for the first 3 isolines:

```
0.583269134728022   0.000000000000000   0.812278964687394  -0.320293867608490
0.580909581594315   0.007973125730173   0.813929043146888  -0.320665285931309
0.579785325817111   0.012185401198738   0.814678152379682  -0.319735882722560
0.577779176822166   0.024297208081169   0.815831397109820  -0.320361504000952
0.576909816434933   0.036417802401094   0.815995592738887  -0.320403630362981
0.577172867984531   0.048629420129673   0.815172779207183  -0.320031224804219
0.578148464427645   0.057130252948393   0.813929043146888  -0.320387777026126
0.578704588686426   0.061029231166495   0.813250534568838  -0.319665984528574
0.581898893812968   0.073759402131091   0.809909394918042  -0.320370811205343
0.584041054767261   0.079921569901134   0.807780037516949  -0.320341055455273
0.587152093378653   0.086997273278812   0.804788104834507  -0.320478211253033
0.590601503183356   0.093383714539404   0.801541855611037  -0.320173483998829
0.596042215369224   0.101156588191631   0.796555724455720  -0.319981798224729
0.597513084292275   0.103009324685663   0.795215186680522  -0.319493035783494
0.604755526713132   0.109836981839419   0.788800729164425  -0.319968447982055
0.612231539743685   0.114806433623806   0.782299191193279  -0.319599051310532
0.619955897752779   0.118011349519371   0.775711290510949  -0.319251561026965
0.627935152093348   0.119492163257610   0.769037754395401  -0.319257222870967
0.636170136196511   0.119238398882330   0.762279320225658  -0.319583116484306
0.644656778638960   0.117187799970443   0.755436732819451  -0.319897036078492
0.653385345210641   0.113222128921684   0.748510748210347  -0.319545744753188
0.656237960886707   0.111372636792196   0.746289403961500  -0.319824548723782
0.662441961221518   0.106514026007355   0.741502130999428  -0.320028872732437
0.669596553710997   0.099212921194814   0.736068781790362  -0.319639428148916
0.671828921177072   0.096360893531959   0.734411654910088  -0.319856071019547
0.678565707237046   0.086012538268465   0.729486411266518  -0.319684173372658
0.681772003292950   0.079427756779437   0.727240102702612  -0.320337731290841
0.684827047650417   0.072220730606254   0.725117977212752  -0.319601522167011
0.688930991201026   0.058045546611462   0.722498999225154  -0.319652323775522
0.691181191781987   0.043631256304872   0.721363205050057  -0.319479428427186
0.691614527370781   0.029084298565262   0.721680988461424  -0.319552181782951
0.690224281889916   0.014506506835243   0.723450068732452  -0.319750268127290
0.686961513615338   0.000000000000000   0.726693799898777  -0.319286016604042
0.686961513615338   0.000000001937516   0.726693799898777  -0.319286021200307
0.686381141993946  -0.001661606506153   0.727240102702612  -0.319748084139062
0.681267133650426  -0.014318253277102   0.731894855994237  -0.319814256140497
0.678426528056456  -0.019415642185852   0.734411654910088  -0.320552648892289
0.672523722943641  -0.028281478779618   0.739534989054651  -0.319820756684516
0.670235269003354  -0.030972147282826   0.741502130999428  -0.320061566856913
0.661990908127392  -0.038725926331818   0.748510748210347  -0.320149857975314
0.657956776530449  -0.041533946530906   0.751909443685360  -0.320193645779542
0.653747723665175  -0.043923302581612   0.755436732819451  -0.319999623121859
0.645546574050700  -0.046902651180004   0.762279320225658  -0.320547546996108
0.637387957706765  -0.048140665604852   0.769037754395401  -0.320528175501465
0.629286045250583  -0.047655713474031   0.775711290510949  -0.320528879789900
0.621242129325082  -0.045455387029261   0.782299191193279  -0.320592277424885
0.613243939726074  -0.041536490690894   0.788800729164425  -0.320127043279225
0.608896928320004  -0.038437011922022   0.792317566886517  -0.320582383119266
0.605288275190454  -0.035481132868440   0.795215186680522  -0.320180231223417
0.597334071364981  -0.026882352764440   0.801541855611037  -0.319876158770855
0.595979532790748  -0.025062584314398   0.802608412217319  -0.319958945695671
0.589311503874503  -0.014260518584128   0.807780037516949  -0.319961856401838
0.588321552504527  -0.012364807549134   0.808532536384861  -0.319745872793599
0.583269134728022   0.000000001645060   0.812278964687394  -0.320293872484342

0.558159737202182   0.000000000000000   0.829733516116103  -0.055396563758039
0.555576228612629   0.011676596389510   0.831383612598495  -0.054546992469172
0.554759697262944   0.017129714752185   0.831834269049572  -0.055715110858570
0.553833812719103   0.023290239471827   0.832301431354270  -0.054539387878562
0.552823669175770   0.034897348897792   0.832567214006740  -0.054716363713811
0.552479184380769   0.046548865791231   0.832225903177443  -0.054478041562892
0.552635274383974   0.051439307356475   0.831834269049572  -0.055499967201189
0.552880010255239   0.058305813730957   0.831218458857440  -0.054649465020374
0.554091969324651   0.070234696813432   0.829487297608261  -0.055373541186727
0.556058144814588   0.082390138652110   0.827049699013454  -0.054911618275994
0.557016910652675   0.086761094925882   0.825956823117414  -0.055091185751908
0.559132795358788   0.094892550336402   0.823629723264599  -0.055355534267779
0.562552529178420   0.105612557154999   0.819988194845600  -0.054635583698716
0.563412866430510   0.107844908320935   0.819106475184884  -0.054788147666652
0.568543120343359   0.119491560506292   0.813929043146888  -0.054486792375866
0.569621277958117   0.121493830207805   0.812878126731676  -0.054857758844573
0.574862427311048   0.130478353205298   0.807780037516949  -0.054613747385908
0.579031542594101   0.136281403161514   0.803834467930696  -0.055241489546315
0.581438122824380   0.139500405125136   0.801541855611037  -0.054362761260458
0.588270705831099   0.146868592740734   0.795215186680522  -0.054405225159820
0.595327497061280   0.152900558901604   0.788800729164425  -0.054200927244066
0.596561614831100   0.153705607343223   0.787711131050819  -0.054745009760534
0.602619359448843   0.157663829319876   0.782299191193279  -0.054208430332702
0.610135182063394   0.161267025092877   0.775711290510949  -0.054207413117559
0.617874711204820   0.163743010745618   0.769037754395401  -0.054196120516853
0.625840393279846   0.165087976835493   0.762279320225658  -0.054186192950839
0.634036216965869   0.165267717000882   0.755436732819451  -0.054177770796666
0.639112857802297   0.164669042605394   0.751278151818089  -0.054851222313917
0.642470470277521   0.164205221095336   0.748510748210347  -0.054218028613133
0.651152605242332   0.161786508737381   0.741502130999428  -0.054316146965666
0.660085457974496   0.157881947362029   0.734411654910088  -0.054262969792322
0.663198707759177   0.156091065546114   0.731985691993523  -0.054628041469859
0.669306468603215   0.152153488645474   0.727240102702612  -0.054452386736291
0.678417480866398   0.144698840123822   0.720286031602523  -0.054237749199198
0.678811938649423   0.144330342075469   0.719988266781751  -0.054222689427672
0.688691388796432   0.133507482298548   0.712656946340906  -0.054359963085139
0.689848669513442   0.132046445780222   0.711809349002488  -0.054290769461822
0.698869290520254   0.118607761661885   0.705346662033127  -0.054184835406492
0.699013720941802   0.118349294273113   0.705246951415001  -0.054224289396256
0.705963846303215   0.104601397754354   0.700480974260262  -0.054371340908575
0.710149695017773   0.093912986218223   0.697759100037928  -0.054853425447671
0.711492424644915   0.090186210045412   0.696882326645284  -0.054230149971236
0.715552659468688   0.075461002936988   0.694471042278245  -0.054312817838620
0.718272168541582   0.060517673281199   0.693125315595386  -0.054309284985517
0.719689012024605   0.045430830752915   0.692808606750918  -0.054307252415357
0.719813985725518   0.030270163572011   0.693506700148792  -0.054327988135421
0.718632611333712   0.015103567292354   0.695225900109264  -0.054324029152539
0.716331364982840   0.001270376354382   0.697759100037928  -0.054585198397574
0.716099682653679   0.000000000000000   0.697998026145705  -0.054202116817946
0.716099682653679   0.000000002019697   0.697998026145705  -0.054202121232168
0.712065584570057  -0.014965547119749   0.701953442665758  -0.054450781128972
0.708539088822910  -0.024476460729600   0.705246951415001  -0.055380144349079
0.706417760712068  -0.029706816618568   0.707171444839891  -0.054467074073809
0.700277619194549  -0.041609288473471   0.712656946340906  -0.054909232357704
0.698837216309104  -0.044114550698979   0.713919079110490  -0.054451011827077
0.691876150883180  -0.054076681995891   0.719988266781751  -0.055158360003076
0.688709499171887  -0.058026882466191   0.722711634513838  -0.054738847282501
0.683429121064577  -0.063611866047110   0.727240102702612  -0.055248329186544
0.674971674348771  -0.071082768369297   0.734411654910088  -0.054200086361744
0.674854063424650  -0.071168995583582   0.734511379862057  -0.054213677439682
0.666584748934357  -0.076415719661775   0.741502130999428  -0.055154254010878
0.658234329821273  -0.080369315402877   0.748510748210347  -0.054861086028195
0.651364450134538  -0.082564605941823   0.754259530232534  -0.054737388807416
0.649948977601747  -0.082955826929263   0.755436732819451  -0.054308702017072
0.641757298801021  -0.084129705763933   0.762279320225658  -0.054748489622146
0.633643188886297  -0.084126342440897   0.769037754395401  -0.054903980025366
0.625611166208641  -0.082961813437880   0.775711290510949  -0.054904529108915
0.617660857705126  -0.080641430526188   0.782299191193279  -0.054720419860737
0.610220907010851  -0.077349398964599   0.788446266480265  -0.054449653777049
0.609787985339296  -0.077149352592962   0.788800729164425  -0.054217955045141
0.602012507711727  -0.072206283876829   0.795215186680522  -0.055140698168297
0.594289021821889  -0.065963719161354   0.801541855611037  -0.055044319778624
0.590566007910610  -0.062280116378816   0.804582486389287  -0.055601259939160
0.586620813242974  -0.058029582621863   0.807780037516949  -0.055254223795089
0.579417130548721  -0.048818507329543   0.813567785847498  -0.054490821588823
0.578964052158368  -0.048167821523861   0.813929043146888  -0.054433114546030
0.571698866953411  -0.036088860269872   0.819669445379421  -0.054456029449611
0.571290754398069  -0.035302043186484   0.819988194845600  -0.054518733455940
0.565993409567750  -0.023801585068302   0.824066104674928  -0.055377737513891
0.563468734868816  -0.017271686979669   0.825956823117414  -0.055691176120551
0.561530630857763  -0.011801740313511   0.827371784347312  -0.055144425247325
0.558159737202182   0.000000001574241   0.829733516116103  -0.055396568601584

0.538469014209320   0.000000000000000   0.842645311347808   0.210286635073196
0.537393883074428   0.005563285857375   0.843313028646337   0.209346397478612
0.536294546736155   0.011271351518712   0.843955636142092   0.210334677450457
0.534682330550564   0.022484866820858   0.844753950071301   0.209966256690795
0.533553802537291   0.033680926199575   0.845095222450308   0.209865244093819
0.532901200599995   0.044899332260849   0.844985420206535   0.209903019873292
0.532719443753549   0.056179713648924   0.844425150040686   0.210114373849072
0.533005441594932   0.067561844716784   0.843410099754951   0.210689879969759
0.533060170954169   0.068337324045176   0.843313028646337   0.210494301866224
0.533911449262243   0.079108702467316   0.841831561264264   0.209937867242749
0.535345038039752   0.090855439693771   0.839732683253587   0.209782202044602
0.536919831945677   0.100548616767590   0.837619883795478   0.210284464545106
0.537358319944195   0.102857712705467   0.837058138317615   0.210376810340956
0.540218530195320   0.115222553865844   0.833599245869525   0.209863847104866
0.541710485020068   0.120836663534240   0.831834269049572   0.210286533542487
0.543972868381129   0.128029960945912   0.829277907317803   0.209709720554994
0.546928126849288   0.136619729200862   0.825956823117414   0.210487106165330
0.548902031288100   0.141425995225913   0.823835692308944   0.209790702073431
0.552460255327209   0.149689767845534   0.819988194845600   0.210639068130979
0.555538048597051   0.155654461506172   0.816791996272126   0.209740679000001
0.558253735275379   0.160848623783602   0.813929043146888   0.210795952613584
0.564291333719684   0.170489594046019   0.807780037516949   0.210771218715459
0.564764168857693   0.171116857565270   0.807316824196961   0.210491649878272
0.570540350017870   0.178925578677566   0.801541855611037   0.210993726856471
0.577019870226704   0.186228022156231   0.795215186680522   0.210893195003645
0.580209546996524   0.189195726070454   0.792188019860666   0.209905716224427
0.583703102850259   0.192572317306124   0.788800729164425   0.210975361697465
0.590592839678518   0.198010285537912   0.782299191193279   0.211158162473033
0.597703755574964   0.202539414301071   0.775711290510949   0.211190513878636
0.605034140836318   0.206190738727368   0.769037754395401   0.211175708998320
0.612585344891282   0.208972326351452   0.762279320225658   0.211173692640134
0.620362429072154   0.210869152089088   0.755436732819451   0.211195866831511
0.628374717544342   0.211841625193575   0.748510748210347   0.211204374172289
0.636636305772068   0.211822576455391   0.741502130999428   0.211113808742427
0.645166516979909   0.210712331153730   0.734411654910088   0.210794739738056
0.645767759618627   0.210573060692275   0.733923011458169   0.210663968245281
0.653923697997208   0.208580033125780   0.727240102702612   0.211035744205873
0.662978713895058   0.205124646541230   0.719988266781751   0.211001578352134
0.668211650840843   0.202460220009456   0.715893182670626   0.210509126489056
0.672336493042872   0.200209182993355   0.712656946340906   0.210895150586834
0.682011565624992   0.193615500086111   0.705246951415001   0.210847860809886
0.684338792254629   0.191742737450988   0.703502054048372   0.210655073051410
0.692042038733174   0.184959603536268   0.697759100037928   0.210802443698911
0.697225426364559   0.179641892723593   0.693978022137188   0.210676836927685
0.702487290636051   0.173618970094194   0.690194218838619   0.210676851679256
0.707929874595294   0.166619034634235   0.686347863661749   0.210738234140917
0.713435206408623   0.158528903692808   0.682553142949794   0.210551009534247
0.716923092624211   0.152911655266053   0.680175936758963   0.210792674091535
0.724461815375409   0.138671874066644   0.675222325908891   0.210768712728971
0.725079672966319   0.137313050024651   0.674836716653727   0.210606669189839
0.730732971800068   0.124015468032976   0.671304318184237   0.210872009486129
0.735805926120890   0.109023045232722   0.668358896621840   0.210829387209572
0.738350244365693   0.099442597658434   0.667045790344309   0.210120844599855
0.739768410872408   0.093770371935015   0.666295591777764   0.210821044478838
0.742666955609170   0.078320431874350   0.665065187028477   0.210901732612498
0.744509455039987   0.062728283133060   0.664658433972849   0.210923156344180
0.745307207773903   0.047047995800367   0.665059134311707   0.210906195846072
0.745053542219268   0.031331556541169   0.666268378951927   0.210826883266447
0.744584841354193   0.025363903672094   0.667045790344309   0.209783688766630
0.743743977460171   0.015631335170005   0.668281794868398   0.210829260439485
0.741341789029431   0.000000000000000   0.671127671787300   0.210879346557002
0.741341789029431   0.000000002090891   0.671127671787300   0.210879342296080
0.737806999590985  -0.015370010102946   0.674836716653727   0.210720402779938
0.737774097743270  -0.015505865278090   0.674869579134429   0.210758819880074
0.732991988093578  -0.030824336227372   0.679538524063769   0.210783553537481
0.729800984286506  -0.038880977145700   0.682553142949794   0.209744827549457
0.726853989847962  -0.045883127626278   0.685257627495914   0.210703074086476
0.721410680085557  -0.056555909861319   0.690194218838619   0.209985836812971
0.719190444143130  -0.060595039596928   0.692165692756766   0.210639341406866
0.712866621160467  -0.070380528198647   0.697759100037928   0.209991263317329
0.709697550208836  -0.074843532185579   0.700519687744436   0.210521389664901
0.704261563766489  -0.081500842455934   0.705246951415001   0.209972988774258
0.697854843049017  -0.088457560293679   0.710755849824623   0.210482566032738
0.695639447822076  -0.090586066620936   0.712656946340906   0.210394094795940
0.687055236118021  -0.097836589369317   0.719988266781751   0.210229334269447
0.682457446597624  -0.101118498859845   0.723897011163731   0.210218760445291
0.678512815062502  -0.103644550349035   0.727240102702612   0.210394191591412
0.670041922881492  -0.108089512504676   0.734411654910088   0.210240461727980
0.661636178065855  -0.111409863107876   0.741502130999428   0.210631324878594
0.659691651684611  -0.111958773182046   0.743150158316071   0.210184664437210
0.653326211913121  -0.113562848858413   0.748510748210347   0.210504149608688
0.645107381148954  -0.114681338910092   0.755436732819451   0.210364886329588
0.636981423059394  -0.114825539988013   0.762279320225658   0.210326386246206
0.628952224980543  -0.114017678482345   0.769037754395401   0.210313687718955
0.621021242720635  -0.112270253689726   0.775711290510949   0.210294104510636
0.613187461827387  -0.109586094537710   0.782299191193279   0.210286800437244
0.605447132709003  -0.105958384114320   0.788800729164425   0.210381884996189
0.597989641409482  -0.101487090911051   0.795052676962584   0.210631723108054
0.597793815476161  -0.101367455581746   0.795215186680522   0.210740012318680
0.590243229002130  -0.095622091175393   0.801541855611037   0.210110674298258
0.582755841468409  -0.088809009810735   0.807780037516949   0.210294553798191
0.580082260040190  -0.085949750629763   0.810010624592880   0.209533154459488
0.575342022667940  -0.080629211048823   0.813929043146888   0.209921551307113
0.568749761589268  -0.072092666302904   0.819345077581778   0.210248804542981
0.567960444294131  -0.070995028213731   0.819988194845600   0.210444577677214
0.560599330659940  -0.059360903037396   0.825956823117414   0.210674069787450
0.560454056014059  -0.059104559635979   0.826073787338411   0.210659533210474
0.554042784137539  -0.046680604166266   0.831178389119806   0.210249109307868
0.553208121490080  -0.044861154155700   0.831834269049572   0.210115527328045
0.548915890563241  -0.034650670168397   0.835159072359299   0.209565173745684
0.545645336282332  -0.025770084667896   0.837619883795478   0.209767912961772
0.544653638796982  -0.022904188807581   0.838348264076615   0.210248876997223
0.541272973320265  -0.011375983283565   0.840769977673663   0.209630112864974
0.538469014209320   0.000000001518705   0.842645311347808   0.210286630269143
```

---

### So far

I managed only to correctly plot the heat map, analogous to [GNUPLOT: Plotting on the surface of a sphere](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28627187/gnuplot-plotting-on-the-surface-of-a-sphere), by providing the data simply as a big set of points (x,y,z,value).
The result is the following picture:
[image]