# Is it possible to plot on a surface in Matplotlib?

Tags: matplotlib

In [GNUPlot](http://www.gnuplot.info/) it is possible to plot a function on a surface (see, for example, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28627187/gnuplot-plotting-on-the-surface-of-a-sphere)). Similar thing can be done in [Mathematica](http://www.wolfram.com/?source=nav) (see [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/11586/spherical-density-plot-of-data-set)).

Is it possible to do the same thing in Matplotlib? Alternatively, is it possible to map the colourmap by the function that one intends to plot on the surface?

A good example of this is plotting an ellipsoid, and visualising the Gauss curvature at each point on it with the colourmap.

Comment: You cannot plot something *onto*  a surface, but you can colorize the surface according to whatever you want to plot.For that use the `facecolors` argument to `plot_surface`

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for. Thanks, @ImportanceOfBeingErnest!